# How to use IF statement before FROM Clause

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

[image: Company Table]

[image: feeds table]

[image: user table]

Users and companies can add feeds. The flag columns means

```
0 = user
1 = company
```

How can I perform this SQL query correctly? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
SELECT 
feeds.feeds_id,
feeds.title
IF feeds.flag = 0
FROM user
INNER JOIN 
feeds.user_or_company = user.user_id
ELSEif feeds.flag = 1
INNER JOIN
feeds.user_or_company = company.company_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to `LEFT JOIN` to both `user` and `company` tables and then select the appropriate `name` value based on `feeds.flag`:

```
SELECT f.feeds_id, f.title,
       CASE f.flag WHEN 0 THEN u.name ELSE c.name END AS name
FROM feeds f
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.user_id = f.user_or_company
LEFT JOIN company c ON c.company_id = f.user_or_company
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
feeds_id    title                           name
2           This title added twice by user  User-1
3           This title added by company     Company-2
1           This title added by user        User-3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kLWBD9PxUYWXUGNAkhnXzN/0)